# Custom mapping with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to map JSON that looks like

```
"ids": {
    "id": {
        "@value":"6763754764235874140"
    }
}
```

And I'd like to map it onto a couple of classes that look like

```
class Property
{
    public Ids Ids { get; set; }
}

class Ids
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

So basically I want to stuff the value of `ids/id/@value` from the JSON document into `Ids.Id` in the class architecture.  From browsing the documentation, I thought I could use something like

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(IdConverter))]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

and provide a custom `JsonConverter` subclass named `IdConverter`.  When I do, though, my `IdConverter.ReadJson` never gets called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your property's name is `Id`, but `id` in json. It might be a `case` problem

Comment: Turns out Json.NET is smart enough to deserialize `ids` into the `Ids` property, though it will respect case on serializing unless you tell it not to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like the answer was that `ItemConverterType` is for converting items in an array.  Double-annotating the property with `JsonProperty` and `JsonConverter` attributes works:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverter))]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Late one here. But I had the same problem, using `JsonProperty`. I changed it to `JsonConverter` and it's working, without the need for the extra `JsonProperty` attribute. Might have just been a bug in an older version but on up-to-date versions (specifically v4), you can just use `JsonConverter`

Comment: It's been quite a while since I messed with this, but I believe the `JsonProperty` attribute was necessary in order to serialize `Id` (uppercase first letter) into a JSON field named `id` (lowercase). Does the newer version handle this correctly without the extra attribute?

Comment: It looks as though it does, yes. I think that's probably more a configuration item in the default serializer settings that's changed that in newer versions however. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass())` out of the box seems to use the serializable class properties names' as-is.